# (android) why need to import google play services library project to ide?

Tags: android, google-maps

This.

Isn't there a way to only add the jar file instead of the hole project as library?

I tried it but with no luck. Got a NoClassDefFound.

Why isn't there just a jar file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't there a way to only add the jar file instead of the hole project as library?

No, because the Play Services SDK is more than a JAR file. It contains resources as well, and is packaged as an Android library project. A JAR is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The Google play services library is a library that accesses different api like Maps, Google+ will help you achieve integration of some services natively.

If you want to add, read official android documentation you provide a simple step by step manual for you to do.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html